# replace newline with nul

Tags: text-processing, osx, newlines

bash, osx mavericks

I want to replace the LF character (hex=`0A`) with NUL (hex=`00`) in a txt file. can I use `grep` or `tr` or something to accomplish this? I've been using bbedit to replace them, but I'd like something I can do quickly in bash.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that's a job for `tr`:

```
tr '\n' '\0' < file > file.new
```

Or in-place:

```
tr '\n' '\0' < file 1<> file
```

Here, the file is written over itself. That works because we're always writing as much data as we're reading (and not overwriting data we've not read yet). If the `tr` process is interrupted, it can be started again to finish the job.

Contrary to `perl -pi 's/\n/\0/'`, that preserves all attributes of the file and doesn't break hardlinks or symlinks and doesn't need to duplicate the data on-disk (unless there's some copy-on-write going on underneath).

Comment: It seems slightly dangerous to recommend `1<>` here without explaining what it does and why it works in _this particular_ case.

Comment: Also works to achieve the opposite, replace nul with newline.