# How does the "1<>file" shell input/output redirection work?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, tr

I saw this piece of code on another question, but I wasn‘t able to comment on the answer so I‘m asking here.

```
tr '\n' '\0' < file 1<> file
```

I‘m interested in the `1<>` part, never seen that before and I couldn‘t find anything helpful on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was in an answer that [Stéphane Chazelas wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434530/replace-newline-with-nul/434531#434531). It is [a POSIX shell feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_07) and not specific to `bash`.  It will be mentioned in the manual of your shell, together with the descriptions of the other redirection operators.

The `1<>file` opens standard output, file descriptor 1, for both reading and writing and attaches it to the file named `file` in the current directory.

Before that happens, he has already attached standard input from the same file.

`tr` will then read from its standard input, from `file`, and will change all newline characters to nul characters.  The output from `tr` is written back to the same file.

This works as long as the result of the `tr` command is exactly as long as the original data in `file`.

If the result of `tr` is shorter than the original file, you will end up with "old data" at the end of the file:

```
$ cat file
too many @ here: @@@@
the end
$ tr -s '@' <file 1<>file
$ cat file
too many @ here: @
the end
nd
```

Note that he can't use `>` as in

```
tr '\n' '\0' <file >file
```

since that would truncate `file` before `tr` had a chance to read from it (`1<>` does not truncate the output file, but it does create it if it does not already exist).

He also can not use `>>` as in

```
tr '\n' '\0' <file >>file
```

as that would append the output from `tr` at the end of the file and leave the old data in place.